# How to set Spring profiles for deploying to Heroku

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring web app, with 3 different profiles for `prod` `dev` and `test` Each of these uses a different database, local for test and dev and a heroku postgres for prod.

I have set up my application.yaml file as below,

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-35-168-65-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/*******
    username: username
    password: ******************
    jpa:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        show-sql: true
      javax:
        persistence:
          validation:
            mode: none
    show-sql: true
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        default-page-size: 10
        max-page-size: 100

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-35-168-65-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/********
    username: username
    password: **********
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
syftgolf:
  upload-path: uploads-prod
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
    username: postgres
    password: admin
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
syftgolf:
  upload-path: uploads-dev

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/syftgolf
    username: postgres
    password: admin
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop

syftgolf:
  upload-path: uploads-test
```

I have slowly been updating this app over the months from a barebones project I did. I cant for the life of me, remember what this first part does.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-35-168-65-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/*********
    username: username
    password: *********
    jpa:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        show-sql: true
      javax:
        persistence:
          validation:
            mode: none
    show-sql: true
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        default-page-size: 10
        max-page-size: 100
```

I think `spring:profiles:active: -dev` sets the active profile to dev, so it should then use the database under dev? But I cant remember why the rest of the lines are placed here and not under a specific profile,

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-35-168-65-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/***********
    username: username
    password: *************************
    jpa:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
        show-sql: true
      javax:
        persistence:
          validation:
            mode: none
    show-sql: true
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        default-page-size: 10
        max-page-size: 100
```

if I remove this and just leave the active profile part, I get an error that the app cant start.

Please could someone help with the best way of laying out this application.yaml file and also is setting active profile in this file the correct way of doing it?

So if I am working on the app, i set this to `dev` do I then need to change it to `prod` before I push it to heroku using the heroku cli?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to save an environment variable in your heroku application which will be using by your application to set the profile.

For example, this is a configuration for a simple spring boot thymeleaf application.

```yaml
server:
  port: ${PORT:4000}

spring:
  application:
    name: PROFILE-TEST

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev

custom:
  message: "This is development environment"

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: prod

custom:
  message: "This is production environment"

---

spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${PROFILE:dev}
```

Here I'm using `spring.config.activate.on-profile` to set an environment to have different `custom.message`.

By Default I'm setting the active profile with `spring.profiles.active=${PROFILE:dev}`. `PROFILE` is the environment variable we're gonna use to set different value during deployment. If there is no environment variable set for `PROFILE`, it'll default back to `dev`.

Now if I've written a controller which will only act on profile `dev` with the `@Profile` annotation like this

```java
@Profile("dev")
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DevHomeController {
    private final CustomConfigurationProperties customConfigurationProperties;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        modelAndView.addObject("message", customConfigurationProperties.getMessage());
        modelAndView.setViewName("dev-home.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

It'll show something like

[image: dev-instance]

I've written another controller which will have a profile value `@Profile("prod")`

In the console type the below command to set an environment variable in heroku.

```bash
heroku config:set PROFILE=prod
```

And deploy the application. I'll look like

[image: prod-instance]

The message you see on the screen is coming from `custom.message` property you have set in your application.yml, and as we have set the environment variable for `PROFILE`, heroku is using that to set the running profile.